# How to select files from local and list them in webpage using HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to front end and trying to design a webpage. which will be something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6SHl.png)

There are two navigation tabs:

1: file upload: we will select some files using drag and drop or browse from our local path.(c drive)

2: files available: This will show list off all files which we have selected from local in below format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kERS9.png)

So as I am new to front end, I don't know how to interact with local machine(laptop) to get files and show them on webpage in a list format.

I would appreciate some help if you guys can provide me some guidence.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: create a snippet what you tried yet?

Comment: Start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file and have a go then if you get stuck put the code you have so far into your question describing what isn't working.

Comment: @AmanSharma I have tried only selecting files: <input type="file" id="MyFile" multiple > . After this I don't know how to show these selected files as list in webpage with some icons and all. Refer to second image I have posted.